# Two Port Circuit

Tags: voltage, current, circuit-analysis

I hope all are well.

Please can you help me with the below, I have a idea of doing it but I am so confused in determining the correct ANSWER. I am using the linear and nonlinear text book by Leon O. Chuao 1987, does anyone have the solution manual for this book?

The question is for the two-port circuit determine the conductance matrix?

I attempted the solution but not sure how to add the annoying dependent source in my equations please help me.

thank you all.

[image: two port circuit question]

[image: my solution]

---

Thank you very much, I really appreciate your response.

Please can you tell me in the Matrix will now it become alter since it will be 2- 1/R2 [image: final solution]

Comment: There are two sentences that end with a question mark. The first one asks if anyone has the book (I don't) and the second one is not a question. So what is your actual question?

Comment: Not many people are going to have the actual textbook, and even if they did, you don't provide which actual question it is.  If you want actual help, post the actual question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the solutions book but I can see a simple mistake in your third equation. Everything else seems ok to me.

You should had written: \$i_2=2v_1+i_3'-i_2'\$ instead of \$i_2=i_3'-i_2'\$

because you must take into account the \$2v_1\$ current drawn by the dependent voltage controlled current source.